# How to send data obtained from a form as form data instead of request payload?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have form where when submitted the data is being sent as request payload and not as form data.

```
define(['app-module'], function(app) {
    'use strict';
    return app.factory('transformRequestAsFormPost', function() {
        function transformRequest(data, getHeaders) {
            var headers = getHeaders();
            headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
            return (serializeData(data));
        }

        function serializeData(data) {
            if (!angular.isObject(data)) {
                return ((data === null) ? "" : data.toString());
            }
            var buffer = [];
            for (var name in data) {
                if (!data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    continue;
                }
                var value = data[name];
                buffer.push(
                    encodeURIComponent(name) +
                    "=" +
                    encodeURIComponent((value == null) ? "" : value)
                );
            }
            var source = buffer.join("&").replace(/%20/g, "+");
            return (source);
        }
        return (transformRequest);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show your HTML.

Comment: What do you mean by _"not as form data"_? No reference to `FormData` appears at `javascript` at Question?